# alternative to _LSCopyDefaultSchemeHandlerURL

Tags: macos, cocoa

Apparently _LSCopyDefaultSchemeHandlerURL is a private API not allowed for the Mac Store. Does anyone know an alternative method which can be used to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

What about the public function [`LSCopyDefaultHandlerForURLScheme()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000998-CH1g-LSCopyDefaultHandlerForURLScheme)?